# Can't install plugins on redmine war

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm running tomcat 7.0.40 and have deployed redmine 2.3.1 and also 2.0.3. 
I've made the WEB-INF/public/plugin_assets directory writable and then copied the plugin into this directory.

After that, i've restarted tomcat but i can't see anything under plugin's list in
redmine>administrator>plugins

What i'm missing?

Thank you very much